# 2d signal result in generate block when port mapped after the block is leading to unknown output while designing a 8 by 32 memory

Tags: memory, multidimensional-array, vhdl

Please help me,I am trying to develop a 8 by 32 bit read/write memory using structural modelling. I've developed the following modules

0) output_array_types (package)

1) register_32_bit

2) dmux_1by8

3) mux_8by1 (32 bit wide)

4) xor_1bit (not relevant to my problem)

5) data_memory_2pow3_32 (this is where my problem occurs)

All modules have been tested independently and they all work except the main file (5th one), due to some lack of understanding about vhdl syntax the mux_8by1 used in the main file gives unknown output for a 2d signal input (which contains all 8 register values of the memory) from which the mux is supposed to pick the row based on the address asserted at the selection line to get that row value as the output.

I've attached the code and output below. Please help where in the main file i'm going wrong, I'm particularly doubtful about the "unit11" in the main file.

thanks in advance

output_array_types.vhd

```
library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package output_array_types is

    type op_arr is array(0 to 7) of STD_LOGIC;
    type op_arr_32bit is array(0 to 7) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);

end package output_array_types;
```

register_32_bit.vhd

```
library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity register_32_bit is
    port(
        rst: in STD_LOGIC;
        enable: in STD_LOGIC;
        load: in STD_LOGIC;
        data_in: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
        data_out: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0)
    );
end register_32_bit;

architecture behavioral of register_32_bit is

begin
     process(rst,enable,load)
     begin
          if (rst = '0') then
                data_out<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(0, 32));
          elsif (enable = '1') then
                if (load = '1') then
                      data_out<=data_in;
                end if;
          end if;
     end process;
end behavioral;
```

dmux_1by8.vhd

```
library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

use work.output_array_types.all;

entity dmux_1by8 is
    port(data_in: in STD_LOGIC;
        sel: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
        data_out: out op_arr
    );
end dmux_1by8;

architecture behavioral of dmux_1by8 is
begin
    process(sel)
    begin
        data_out<= (others =>'0');
        data_out(to_integer(unsigned(sel)))<= data_in;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

mux_8by1.vhd

```
library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

use work.output_array_types.all;

entity mux_8by1 is
    port(data_in: in op_arr_32bit;
        sel: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
        data_out: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0)
    );
end mux_8by1;

architecture behavioral of mux_8by1 is

begin
    process(sel)
    begin
        data_out<= data_in(to_integer(unsigned(sel)));
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

xor_1bit.vhd

```
library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity xor_1bit is
    port(op: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
        result: out STD_LOGIC
    );
end xor_1bit;

architecture behavioral of xor_1bit is
begin
    process(op)
    begin
        if(op = "00") then
        result<= '0';
        elsif(op = "01") then
        result<= '1';
        elsif(op = "10") then
        result<= '1';
        elsif(op = "11") then
        result<= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

data_memory_2pow3_32.vhd

```
library ieee,work;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.output_array_types.all;


entity data_memory_2pow3_32 is
    port(mem_write: in STD_LOGIC := '1';
        mem_read: in STD_LOGIC := '0';
        address: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        write_data: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        read_data: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
        mem_rst: in STD_LOGIC := '1'
    );
end data_memory_2pow3_32;

architecture structural of data_memory_2pow3_32 is
    component register_32_bit is
    port(
        rst: in STD_LOGIC;
        enable: in STD_LOGIC;
        load: in STD_LOGIC;
        data_in: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
        data_out: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

    component dmux_1by8 is
    port(data_in: in STD_LOGIC;
        sel: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
        data_out: out op_arr
    );
    end component;

    component mux_8by1 is
    port(data_in: in op_arr_32bit;
        sel: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
        data_out: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

    component xor_1bit is
    port(op: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
        result: out STD_LOGIC
    );
    end component;


signal dmux_1by8_out : op_arr;
signal mux_8by1_in : op_arr_32bit;
signal read_xor_write: STD_LOGIC;
signal mux_8by1_out: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
alias address_0to2 is address(2 downto 0);

begin
    unit0: xor_1bit port map(op(0) => mem_write, op(1) => mem_read, result => read_xor_write);

    unit1: dmux_1by8 port map(data_in => mem_write, sel => address_0to2, data_out => dmux_1by8_out);

    unit: for i in 0 to 7 generate
        unit2to9: register_32_bit port map(rst => mem_rst ,enable => read_xor_write ,load => dmux_1by8_out(i),data_in => write_data,data_out => mux_8by1_in(i));
        end generate;

    --Till here everything works, after this when the mux_8by1_in (2d signal
    --array) is mapped to the mux_8by1 below, the output read_data 
    --turns out to be unknown whereas there's no problem in mux_8by1 module 
    --when tested independently. Hence there must be some erroneous mapping 
    --being performed here.

    unit11: mux_8by1 port map(data_in => mux_8by1_in, sel => address_0to2, data_out => read_data);

end structural;
```

[1 [output i got in modelsim]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/McvV4.png

[2 [diagram of memory architecture I'm using]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJb7n.jpg

Comment: A lack of understanding simulation, not syntax. Simulation uses delta cycles to emulate parallelism. Your sensitivity lists are incomplete in some processes (data_in for register_32_bit and mux_8by1 (where data_in has been delayed a delta cycle by the update to unit[0]/unit2to9 data_out - the register output) , ... . If some of the signals evaluated aren't in the sensitivity list you may not act on them. Signal assignments are not updated in the current simulation cycle. Correct you sensitivity lists, use a testbench. Ask a specific question.

Comment: With `data_in` added to the sensitivity lists of the processes in `register_32_bit`, `dmux_1by8`,  `mux_8by1`, and a testbench [your model simulates successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2o91.jpg).